# ¿Puedo utilizar la variable i de un bucle for fuera del propio bucle?

Tags: python, variables, bucles, variables-globales

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación, y creo que la pregunta es algo absurda, tengo entendido que no se puede utilizar la variable que has declarado dentro de un bucle fuera del mismo.

El caso es que estoy intentando crear un programa que valide la dirección de un correo electrónico, esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora:

```
print("Programa que verifique una dirección de correo electrónico")
print("----------------------------------------------------------")
email_usuario = str(input("Por favor, introduzca su dirección de correo electrónico: "))
def validar_correo():
    for i in email_usuario:
        if(i == "@" and "."):
            print("El correo es válido")
        else:
            print("El correo no es correcto")
            break 
validar_correo()
```

Este `while` de aquí abajo tiene el propósito de que la función se ejecute siempre que el correo no tenga ni @ y un . (De esto viene la pregunta, puesto que no reconoce la variable `i`, el motivo de ese `while` es porque en el `else` del bucle `for`, al introducir un correo inválido me ejecutaba el `print` tantas veces como caracteres tenía el string)

```
 while i != email_usuario:
    validar_correo()
```

Espero haberme explicado con propiedad.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la variable asociada a un ciclo `for` con las mismas reglas que otra variable, no hay diferencia en eso:

```
for i in range(8):
    pass

print(i * 3) # 21
```

Tu problema no es que la variable esté asociada al ciclo `for`, tu problema es un problema de ámbito. La variable `i` es una variable local a la función `validar_correo` (toda variable en Python definida dentro de una función es de ámbito local si no se especifica lo contrario) y por tanto inaccesible desde fuera de la misma:

---

```
def foo():
    for i in range(8):
        pass

foo()
print(i * 3)
```

> NameError: name 'i' is not defined

---

```
def foo():
    global i
    for i in range(8):
        pass

foo()
print(i * 3)
```

> 21

No obstante, hay muchos más problemas de lógica en tu código:

- `i` es la variable asociada al `for` encargado de iterar sobre la cadena, por lo que en cada iteración es un carácter de la misma. Suponiendo que la variable se pudiera usar fuera (usando `global` por ejemplo), deberías comparar con el último carácter de la misma, no con la cadena completa:

  ```
  while i == email_usuario[-1]:
  ```
- El condicional está mal:

  ```
  if(i == "@" and "."):
  ```

  equivale a :

  ```
  if (( i == "@") and True)):
  ```

  `"."` no es una cadena vacía, por lo que se evalúa como verdadera siempre.

  en Python tienes que hacer:

  ```
  if i == "@" and i == ".":
  ```

  Pero carece de sentido, `i` no puede ser `@` y `.` al mismo tiempo, se debe usar un `or`:

  ```
  if i == "@" or i == ".":
  ```

  o:

  ```
  if i in "@."
  ```

  pero ésto te obligaría a tener dos variables de control para ver si antes se ha encontrado ya la `@` o el `.` en la cadena. Por lo que mejor directamente usar el operador de pertenencia `in`, recorres la cadena dos veces, pero con el tamaño de la misma (un email) ésto no implica nada:

  ```
  ("@" in email_usuario) and ("." in email_usuario)
  ```
- No es un error en si, pero es redundante e ineficiente, `input` en Python 3 retorna ya una cadena, no hagas el casting explícito a `str` de lo que te retorna.

Tu código con algo más de lógica podría ser:

```
def validar_correo(email_usuario):
    return "@" in email_usuario and "." in email_usuario


print("Programa que verifique una dirección de correo electrónico")
print("----------------------------------------------------------")

while True:
    email_usuario = input(
    "Por favor, introduzca su dirección de correo electrónico: "
    )
    if validar_correo(email_usuario):
        print("El correo es válido")
        break
    print("El correo no es correcto")
```

La función encargada de validar se limita a retornar `True` o `False`, de forma que es más reutilizable.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tomarte las molestias de responder, creo que me he complicado mucho la vida para un ejercicio tan básico, se podía hacer sin necesidad de utilizar un bucle for, seguiré tus instrucciones de sintasix para conseguir un código mas óptimo, Gracias ^^

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios detalles en tu código que habría que revisar, te propongo este enfoque, similar a lo que hiciste pero con algunos cambios que te explico a continuación:

```
def validar_correo(email):
    tiene_arroba = '@' in email
    tiene_punto = '.' in email            
    return tiene_punto and tiene_arroba

print("Programa que verifique una dirección de correo electrónico")
print("----------------------------------------------------------")
email_usuario = str(input("Por favor, introduzca su dirección de correo electrónico: "))

es_valido = validar_correo(email_usuario)
if es_valido:
    print("El correo es válido")
else:
    print("El correo no es correcto")
```

Comentarios sobre el código:

1. Usa `validar_correo()` como una función python que recibe un parámetro y retorna un valor, en este caso recibe el email introducido y retorna un booleano con `True` si es correcto o `False` en caso contrario.
2. No es necesario hacer un bucle para saber si una cadena en python contiene una subcadena o un caracter, podemos usar `'@' in email` para saber si la cadena almacenada en la variable `email` contiene el `'@'`
3. Las variables definidas dentro de una función no se puede usar fuera de una función, piensa en las funciones como fragmentos de código independientes, potencialmente reutilizables en otros escenarios, para ello deben recibir por parámetro todos los datos necesarios para que puedan realizar su algoritmo y deben retornar el resultado del mismo, para que el código desde donde se llama pueda acceder al resultado.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por responder, no tenia ni idea que se podía utilizar el operador in fuera de un condicional, gracias <3